# Как преобразовать тип css-переменной?

Tags: css, css3

Хочу **на чистом css** показать значение `z-index`а элемента в его псевдоэлементе.

Решил использовать для этого css-переменную ([поддержка браузерами](//caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)). Но проблема в том, что для `z-index` в ней должно находиться число, а для `content` - строка. Как привести тип?

В следующем примере в случае, когда срабатывает `z-index`, серебряный `p` показывается поверх красного `div`a. Если же срабатывает `content`, то в конце абзаца отображается число. Как сделать, чтобы одновременно сработали и `z-index`, и `content`?

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: var(--z);
  background: silver;
}

p:after {
  content: var(--z);
  color: red;
}

div {
  background: red;
  z-index: 8;
}

/* дополнительная стилизация и размеры */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1em .5em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 3.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 6em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p style="--z: 9">
  У меня правильный z-index, но нет :after
</p>

<p style="--z: '9'">
  У меня нет z-index, но есть :after
</p>

<div></div>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/42532945/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42532945/4928642

Comment: **Это НЕ вопрос с самоответом, отвечаем :)**

Comment: @mJeevas, вопрос  изначально мой, на обоих сайтах. Как и ответ. Но на SO нашли какой-то более старый вопрос, который сводился к тому же и закрыли мой как дубликат :(

Comment: @Qwertiy решением этого вопроса является точно такое же решение — через счетчики, видимо потому и закрыли

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, в целом да - проблема и решение одинаковые (впрочем, это решение только для чисел). Но мне мой пример больше нравится - вроде достаточно понятный и без скриптов, в отличие от того вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл интересный хак:

```
p:after {
  counter-reset: z var(--z);
  content: counter(z);
}
```

Код полностью:

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: var(--z);
  background: silver;
}

p:after {
  content: var(--z);
  color: red;
}

p.solution:after {
  counter-reset: z var(--z);
  content: counter(z);
  color: red;
}

div {
  background: red;
  z-index: 8;
}

/* дополнительная стилизация и размеры */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1em .5em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 3.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 9em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p style="--z: 9">
  У меня правильный z-index, но нет :after
</p>

<p style="--z: '9'">
  У меня нет z-index, но есть :after
</p>

<p class="solution" style="--z: 9">
  А у меня есть всё!!!
</p>

<div></div>
```

Должно работать в Firefox 31+, Chrome 49+ (Opera 36+), Safari 9.3+.
IE и Edge 14- идут лесом, Edge 15 - неясно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54788/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----css-).